# Facebook error sharing facebook in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

```
Printing description of error:
            Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed.  (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x20918d40 {com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=403, com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
body =     {
    error =         {
        code = 200;
        message = "(#200) Permissions error";
        type = OAuthException;
    };
};
code = 403;
}, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=<FBSession: 0x1fd34770, state: FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended, loginHandler: 0x1fde4440, appID: 463480747117294, urlSchemeSuffix: , tokenCachingStrategy:<FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy: 0x1fd7aeb0>, expirationDate: 2014-09-06 06:09:04 +0000, refreshDate: 2014-07-08 06:25:53 +0000, attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(
installed,
"public_profile"
)>}
```

facebook error is coming when sharing image on facebook....

Comment: Check your permissions, You have to get "publish_stream" permission for sharing anything on Facebook

Answer (score 0):

first check weather u hav set the permission `"publish_actions","publish_stream"`
and so second check like below

```
   NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:mytext, @"message",myImage, @"source",nil]; // set the formats
   if([FBSession.activeSession.permissions indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] != NSNotFound) //checking weather the permission are requested or not
    {
        [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
        {
             //error checkings or success 

        }
    }
```

while opening the session u hav to set the permission's for example

```
 NSArray  *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"publish_actions",@"publish_stream",nil]; //permissions

[FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:permissions allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,FBSessionState state,NSError *error)
        {
            [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
            [FBSession setActiveSession:session];
        }];
```

hope this helps u :)

Comment: where have to set the permission in xcode project or developer facebook.com

Comment: i am created appid and appsecret if u login that id its working rather than if login any other facebookid not working why? this is my code http://pastie.org/9367042

Comment: check weather it in sandbox mode ... in developer Facebook.com ->goto dashboard->This app is public and available to all users[?]->select yes and save settings then check

Comment: At last i found the solution problem is "publish_action" permission denied if u want that permission we have to send request to the facebook site....

Comment: ohh yes glad u found the solution , above code works fine too ,,, :)

Comment: ya posting image it will work but i am getting post id also if i login other account its not working..thats why i sended request to the facbook site..only sharing it is working for me but its not returnig post id value...

Comment: Finally my issue is solved posting image and getting post id what is the issue means u need "publish_action" permission for getting the post id now i submitted my app review to facebook they are accepted now. its working fine right now...

Answer (score 0):

After banging my head for hours, I figured it out.
It seems you need to go into your app Settings on developers.facebook.com, under "Status & Review", and request publish permissions for your app.
If you only need to test it, you can get around by going to Roles and adding the Facebook user you're trying to login with as a developer for your app.